# Python iterating through a nested list to check if the element appears more than 3 times

Tags: python, list, iteration, nested-loops

I have 2 lists in Python.

List 1 is a set, so only unique elemets: `['bird','elephant,'','123','test..,'hi']`

List 2 is a nested list: `[['bird','123',43'],['','bird','33],['123','hello','bird']]`

I would like to check if an element from List 1 appears more than 3 times, anywhere in the nested list. If it does appear 3 or more times, I would like to remove this element from the nested list.

In the example shown above, the element `'bird'` should be removed from list 2, from all 3 nested lists. The output I am after is:`[['123',43'],['','33],['123','hello']]` and I would also like to create a seperate list of the removed items.

Please could someone share how I can approach this?

Comment: what's your current code? what have your tried?

Comment: I have tried this:`for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j.count(i) == 3:
            del(j)` @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: "**more than 3 times**" is not `== 3`. Clarify your conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to count the elements to know if items appear more than  three times. For efficiency, you should avoid using `count()` in a loop and just do it once.

Once you have the counts, you can filter your list with something like:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

s = set(['bird','elephant','','123','test','hi'])
list2 = [['bird','123','43'],['','bird','33'],['123','hello','bird']]

# get counts of all the items that are in s and list2
counts = Counter(word for word in chain.from_iterable(list2) if word in s)

# create lists filter by count <  3
newList = [[item for item in sublist if counts.get(item, 0) < 3] for sublist in list2]

# [['123', '43'], ['', '33'], ['123', 'hello']]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, thank you @MarkMeyer , I was not aware of the itertools module so this is handy to know. How could I know which word from the set were found more than 3 times - wanted to append these to a list? I did 'removed.append(item)` but this returned the number. Thank you!

Comment: @q21311 in the above codes `counts` is dictionary-like: `Counter({'bird': 3, '123': 2, '': 1})`, so you can iterate through it to find values >= 3. Something like: `[key for key, value in counts.items() if value >= 3]`